# VSTO Outlook Add-In Published as Load on demand makes it inactive

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have Outlook Add-in published as ClickOnce and publish option as "Load on-demand", that makes the add-in inactive and the ribbon button not visible at all.

When I go to Options>Add-Ins and then to COM-Ad-ins>Go. my add-in is there in the inactive section with checked tickbox. When I uncheck the box and restart Outlook and then recheck the box and restart outlook again, then add-in it is visible and works perfectly.

I was expecting that publishing as "Load on demand" will make the ribbon button still visible and run the add-in code only when the button is clicked.

Comment: Is there code you're running on the startup of the ribbon?

Comment: @aduguid nop there is only one button in add-in and i have intializeComponent on load of the form. Other than that when You click ribbon button there is [code]Form supportForm = new SupportForm();
            supportForm.Show();[\code]

Comment: Are you looking to show/hide the ribbon?

Comment: @aduguid not looking to hide/show ribbon.